# Amazon MWS determine if product is in BuyBox

Tags: amazon-mws

I am integrating MWS Amazon API. For importing product I need one important field like whether the seller product is buybox winner or not. I need to set flag in our DB.

I have check all the possible API of product in Amazon scratchpad but not get luck how to get this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The winner of the buy box can (and does) change very frequently, depending on the number of sellers for the product.  The best way to get up-to-the-minute notifications of a product's buy box status is to subscribe to the `AnyOfferChangedNotification`: https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/notifications/Notifications_AnyOfferChangedNotification.html

You can use those notifications to update your database.  Another option is the [Products API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/137-3710411-2392445?ie=UTF8&group=products&section=products&version=latest) which has a `GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN` operation which will tell you if your ASIN is currently in the buy box.  http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN.html

Look for `IsBuyBoxWinner`.

Comment: Thanks ScoottG its help a lot

Comment: I don't think `IsBuyBoxWinner` can tell if my offer is currently in the buy box. It only tells if one offer is the winner of buybox, when there are one or many offers to an ASIN.

Answer (score 2):

While the question is old, it could still be useful to someone having a right answer about the product api solution.
In the product api there is GetLowestPricedOffersForSKU (slightly different from GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN ) which has, in addition to the information "IsBuyBoxWinner", the information "MyOffer". The two values combined can tell if you have the buybox.

Keep in mind that the api call limits for both are very strict (200 requests max per hours) so in the case of a very high number of offers the subscription to "AnyOfferChangedNotification" is the only real option. It requires further developing to consume those notifications though, so it is by no means simple to develop.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is that the AnyOfferChangedNotification is not a service that can push to the SQS queue that is a FIFO(First one first-out) style buffer.  You can only push to a standard - random order sqs queue.  I thought I was being smart when I set up two threads in my application, one to download the messages and one to process them.  However when you download messages from download these messages you can get messages from anywhere in the SQS queue. To be successful you need to at least

- Download all the messages to your local cache/buffer/db until amazon returns  'there are no more messages'
- Run your process off of that local buffer that was built and current as the time you got the last 'no more message' returned from amazon
- It is not clear from amazons documentation but I had a concern that I have not proven yet but worth looking in to.  If an asin reprices two or three times quickly it is not clear if the messages could come in to queue out of order (or any one messages could be delayed). By 'out of order' I mean for one sku/asin it is not clear if you can get a message with a more recent 'Time of Offer Change' before one with an older 'Time of Offer Change'  If so that could create a situation where 1)you have a ASIN that reprices at 12:00:00 and again at 12:00:01(Time of Offer Change time). 2) At 12:01:00 you poll the queue and the later 12:00:01 price change is there but not ther earlier one from 12:00:00.  3)You iterate the sqs queue until you clear it and then you do your thing(reprice or send messages or whatever).  Then on the next pass you poll the queue again and you get this earlier AnyOfferChangeNotification.  I added logic in my code to track the 'Time of Offer Change' for any asin/sku and alarm if it rolls backwards.

Other things to consider.
1)If you go out of stock on a ASIN/SKU you stop getting messages 2)You dont start getting messages on ASIN/SKU until you ship the item in for the first time, just adding it to FBA inventory is not enough.   If you need pricing to update that earlier (or when you go out of stock) you also need to poll GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN